# Firefox is not triggering a css focus rule on click while Chrome does.

Tags: javascript, css, firefox

I'm trying to create a navigation bar with the following:

html:

```
<svg height="40" width="40">
  <a href="#">
    <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="20"></circle>
  </a>
</svg>
<svg height="40" width="40">
  <a href="#">
    <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="20"></circle>
  </a>
</svg>
<svg height="40" width="40">
  <a href="#">
    <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="20"></circle>
  </a>
</svg>
```

css:

```
a {
  color: #8899a6;
}

a:focus,
a:hover {
  color: #1da1f2;
}

circle {
  fill: currentcolor;
}
```

where the link turns blue when you hover over it and after you click on it. This is working just fine when I run it in Chrome. However, it's not working in Firefox. Is there a way to make this work in Firefox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you put a `a` element inside a `svg`, it is created using `SVGAElement` prototype, instead of a `HTMLAnchorElement`. And Firefox doesn't implement `focus` method on SVGAElement, while Chrome does.

If you can, you can simply switch the order of your `a` and `svg` element, if it's created outside the `svg`, then your `a` element will be focusable.

```
<a href="#" tabindex="1">
  <svg height="40" width="40">
    <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="20"></circle>
  </svg>
</a>
<svg height="40" width="40">
  <a href="#">
    <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="20"></circle>
  </a>
</svg>
<svg height="40" width="40">
  <a href="#">
    <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="20"></circle>
  </a>
</svg>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2vhnqec0/

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you need to use SVG specifically? Because you can achieve the same result using only HTML and CSS.

```css
a,
a:link,
a:visited,
a:hover,
a:active {
  background-color: #8899a6;
  display: inline-block;

  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

a:focus,
a:hover {
  background-color: #1da1f2;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"></a>
<a href="#"></a>
<a href="#"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have not yet been able to create a `css` solution, though you should be able to use `javascript` `.querySelectorAll()`, `.forEach()` , `click` event

```
var a = document.querySelectorAll("svg a");
[].forEach.call(a, function(el, index) {
  el.onclick = function(e) {
    [].forEach.call(a, function(elem) {
      elem.style.color = "#8899a6"
    })
    this.style.color = "#1da1f2";
  }
})
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9xe4tu7p/1/